# Macro with defcustom leads to "Symbol's value as variable is void" error when byte-compiled

Tags: byte-compilation, elisp-macros

In two of my packages I have a macro where the body depends on a variable defined in a `defcustom` form.

When installing the packages from Melpa, the byte-compilation ends with:

> Error: Symbol's value as variable is void: my-defcustom-variable

Then, manually byte-compiling the file by opening it in a buffer works.

I tried with an `autoload` cookie but still have the same behavior.

I'm missing something important here.

Comment: Depending on a `defcustom` in a macro body is a strange thing to do, for the `defcustom` will only ever come into effect during byte-compilation (where the macro is expanded).  This doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, you are right and it explains a lot of things.

Comment: As a scenario where such a thing might be useful: I was trying to do something similar: a macro that was checking if a argument corresponds to a defcustom variable and take a decision based on that.  I was trying to improve error checking on code that was adding properties to these defcustom variables right after the defcustom form.  Stefan's explained why that does not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `defcustom` expression are not evaluated during byte-compilation, so when your macro is expanded, the variable does not exist yet because that defcustom was compiled but not run.  You can either move the defcustom to another file (which you then `require` at the beginning of your file), or you can wrap the defcustom inside `eval-and-compile`.